# Mahavakyas According to Shri Adi Shankaracharya

Tags: advaita, vedanta, mahavakyas

I have read the Mahavakyas, which are central to the Advaita School, from the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81v%C4%81kyas) Wikipedia page; however, did Shri Adi Shankaracharya mention them in his works or were they promoted to Mahavakyas by his followers because of the Advaita-like message they carry? If the former is so, what verses from Shri Adi Shankaracharya's works declare that the Mahavakyas carry the purport of the Vedas?

Comment: Mahavakyas are part of the Upanishads. Adi Shankara did write commentaries on Upanishads including Mahavakyas.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mahavakyas with Shankara Bhasya

1. [**Tat Tvam Asi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81v%C4%81kyas#:%7E:text=That%27s%20how%20%5Bthus%5D%20you%20are%2C%22%5B4%5D%5B6%5D%5B10%5D%5B11%5D%20with%20tat%20in%20Ch.U.6.12.3%20referring%20to%20%22the%20very%20nature%20of%20all%20existence%20as%20permeated%20by%20%5Bthe%20finest%20essence): Ch Upanishad: *6.8.7*

[`[Now, that which is this Subtle Essence,—in that has all this its Self; that is the Self; that is the Truth;` **that thou art** `, O ‘Śvetaketu’.—‘Revered Sir, please explain this to me again’.—‘Be it so, my boy’,—he said.]`](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc1145311.html#:%7E:text=Now%2C%20that%20which%20is%20this%20Subtle%20Essence%2C%E2%80%94in%20that%20has%20all%20this%20its%20Self%3B%20that%20is%20the%20Self%3B%20that%20is%20the%20Truth%3B%20that%20thou%20art%2C%20O%20%E2%80%98%C5%9Avetaketu%E2%80%99.%E2%80%94%E2%80%98Revered%20Sir%2C%20please%20explain%20this%20to%20me%20again%E2%80%99.%E2%80%94%E2%80%98Be%20it%20so%2C%20my%20boy%E2%80%99%2C%E2%80%94he%20said.)

Commentary:

> That which has been spoken of above as named ‘Being’—which is the
> subtlest essence,—the point of ultimate subtlety,—source of the
> Universe—in that has all this its Self:—‘that which has this Being for
> its Self’ is Sadātmā’, and the abstract form of this is ‘aitadātmya’.
> That is, it is through this Self known as ‘Being’ that all this
> Universe is imbued with Self; and there is no other Self for this
> which passes through births and deaths; as has been declared in such
> other Vedic texts as—‘other than this, there is no Seer, other than
> this, there is no Heaven’ (Bṛhadā. Upa. III. viii. 11.)—that through
> which all this Universe becomes imbued with Self is its origin, called
> ‘Being’, which is True and Absolutely Real. Hence, it is this that is
> the Self of the Universe, its counter-form, its very essence, its very
> Soul. The term ‘Self’ (Ātman), without any qualifying prefix has its
> denotation restricted by convention to the Self in Evolution,
> (Jīvātmā), like the term ‘cow’ and the like; hence, thou art that
> Being, O Śvetaketu.—Having been thus taught, the son said—‘Revered
> Sir, please explain to me again; I still have doubts with regard to
> what you have told me in regard to all creatures, during deep sleep,
> becoming merged in Being; if that is so, then, having become so
> merged, that they do not know that they had been so merged in Being,
> seems to me doubtful. Hence, please explain this to me further, by
> means of illustrations.’—Being thus addressed, the father said—‘Be it
> so, my dear’.—(7)

Src: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/chandogya-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc1145311.html

*Tat Tvam Asi commentary by Shankara*:

> “Tat tvam asi”—thou art that. This is called the mahāvākya, the great
> saying, it is the magic formula. If your mind has been purified, as
> soon as the mahāvākya is uttered your eyes are opened and you realize
> your own Self. But this can happen only after a long process of
> preparation. It does not come by a fluke. After years of hard work and
> after shedding many tears, at last one day your mind becomes pure and
> free from ego. You have attained cittaśuddhi, purification of the
> mind. Your mind is then like a clean mirror. Now there is a layer of
> dust on the
>
> Once you know who you are you can never be deluded. Can there be
> darkness where there is light? If you are really enlightened there can
> be no room for ignorance in your mind. But without cittaśuddhi, even
> if the teacher tells you that you are the Self, you will not believe
> it. You will think: ‘No, that is nonsense. I am this body.’ The father
> is again telling Śvetaketu, ‘You are That,’ but still it is not clear
> to him.

2. [**Ahaṁ Brahmāsmi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81v%C4%81kyas#:%7E:text=Aha%E1%B9%81%20Brahm%C4%81smi%20(%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BF)%20%2D%20%22I%20am%20Brahman%22%2C%20or%20%22I%20am%20Divine%22%5B14%5D%20(Brihadaranyaka%20Upanishad%201.4.10%20of%20the%20Yajur%20Veda)): Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.10

[[`ब्रह्म वा इदमग्र आसीत्, तदात्मानमेवावेत्, अहम् ब्रह्मास्मीति । तस्मात्तत्सर्वमभवत्; तद्यो यो देवानाम् प्रत्यबुभ्यत स एव तदभवत्, तथार्षीणाम्, तथा मनुष्याणाम्; तद्धैतत्पश्यन्नृषिर्वामदेवः प्रतिपेदे, अहम् मनुरभवं सूर्यश्चेति । तदिदमप्येतर्हि य एवं वेद,` **अहम् ब्रह्मास्मीति**, `स इदं सर्वम् भवति, तस्य ह न देवाश्चनाभूत्या ईशते, आत्मा ह्येषां स भवति; अथ योऽन्यां देवतामुपास्ते, अन्योऽसावन्योऽहमस्मीति, न स वेद, यथा पशुरेवम् स देवानाम् । यथा ह वै बहवः पशवो मनुष्यम् भुञ्ज्युः, एवमेकैकः पुरुषो देवान् भुनक्ति; एकस्मिन्नेव पशावादीयमानेऽप्रियम् भवति, किंउ बहुषु? तस्मादेषाम् तन्न प्रियम् यदेतन्मनुष्याविद्युः ॥ १० ॥`]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117939.html#:%7E:text=%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%20%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%20%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%2C%20%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%2C%20%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%20%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF%20%E0%A5%A4%20%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%3B%20%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%20%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%20%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%20%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AD%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%A4,%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%20%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%83%20%E0%A5%A5%20%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A6%20%E0%A5%A5)

*Shankara's commentary*:

> Prima facie view: Brahman here must be the conditioned Brahman,[23]
> for then only can the identity with all be t(?)roduct of effort. The
> Supreme Brahman cannot (?)me all as a result of knowledge. But this
> identity (?) all is spoken of as a result of knowledge: ‘There (?) It
> became all.’ Hence the Brahman referred to i(?) passage, ‘This was
> indeed Brahman in the beginn(?) must be the conditioned Brahman.
>
> Or, since(?)n alone are qualified (for this identification with(?)the
> word ‘Brahman’ may refer to a future knowe(?) Brahman who will be
> identified with It. For in (?) passage, ‘Men think... we shall become
> all’ ((?). 9), men have been introduced, and it has alread(?)en said
> that they alone are specially qualified for (?) practice of the means
> of prosperity and liberatio(?)neither the Supreme Brahman nor
> Hiraṇyagarbha(?)he conditioned Brahman. Therefore by the word
> (?)ahman’ is meant a man who through the knowledge(?) the conditioned
> Brahman—identified with the who(?)niverse—combined with rites,
> attained identity with(?)e conditioned Brahman (Hiraṇyagarbha), and
> (?)ing away from all enjoyments (in that ! state) and having broken
> his ties of desire and action by attaining everything, sought unity
> with the Supreme Brahman through the knowledge of It.
> ...

Src: [https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117939.html#:~:text=Prima%20facie%20view,knowledge%20of%20It](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117939.html#:%7E:text=Prima%20facie%20view,knowledge%20of%20It).

3. [**Prajñānaṁ Brahma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prajnanam_Brahma): Aitareya Upanishad: *3.3*

[[`He is Brahman, He is Indra, He is Prajapati; He is all these gods; He is the five great elements-earth, air, akasa, water, light; He is all these small creatures and the others which are mixed; He is the origin-those born of an egg, of a womb, of sweat and of a sprout; He is horses, cows, human beings, elephants-whatever breathes here, whether moving on legs or flying in the air or unmoving. All this is guided by Consciousness, is supported by Consciousness. The basis is Consciousness.` **Consciousness is Brahman**]](https://shankaracharya.org/aitareya_upanishad.php#:%7E:text=He%20is%20Brahman,Consciousness%20is%20Brahman)

**No commentary for Ait. Upn. Verse 3-10, as the statements themselves are direct.**

4. [**Ayam Ātmā Brahma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81v%C4%81kyas#:%7E:text=Rig%20Veda): Mandukya Upn. *2*

[[`All this is verily Brahman.` **This Ātman is Brahman.** `This Ātman has four quarters.`]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mandukya-upanishad-karika-bhashya/d/doc143593.html#:%7E:text=All%20this%20is%20verily%20Brahman.%20This%20%C4%80tman%20is%20Brahman.%20This%20%C4%80tman%20has%20four%20quarters.)

*Shankara's commentary*

> All this is verily Brahman. All that has been said to consist merely
> of Aum (in the previous text) is Brahman. That Brahman which has been
> described1 (as existing) inferentially2 is now pointed out, as being
> directly3 known, by the passage, “This Self is Brahman”. The word
> this, meaning that which appears divided into four quarters,4 is
> pointed out as the innermost Self, with a gesture5 (of hand) by the
> passage, “This is Ātman”. That Ātman indicated by Aum, signifying both
> the higher and the lower Brahman, has6 four quarters (Pādas), not
> indeed, like the four feet (Pādas) of a cow,7 but like the four
> quarters (Pādas) of a coin8 known as Kārṣāpaṇa. The knowledge of the
> fourth (Turīya) is attained by merging the (previous) three, such as
> Viśva, etc., in it in9 the order of the previous one, in the
> succeeding one. Here10 the word ‘Pāda’ or ‘foot’ is used in11 the
> sense of instrument. The word ‘Pāda’ is again used in the sense of an
> object when the object to be achieved is the fourth (Turīya).

Src: [https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mandukya-upanishad-karika-bhashya/d/doc143593.html#:~:text=All%20this%20is%20verily%20Brahman.%20All,be%20achieved%20is%20the%20fourth%20(Tur%C4%ABya)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mandukya-upanishad-karika-bhashya/d/doc143593.html#:%7E:text=All%20this%20is%20verily%20Brahman.%20All,be%20achieved%20is%20the%20fourth%20(Tur%C4%ABya)).

Comment: Thank you very much